# Fancybox ajax works fine but second time i click it's not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox, asp.net-ajax

Fancybox ajax post works fine with the simpliest way but second time i click it throws Uncaught TypeError: $.fancybox is not a function error. Could not figure out any workaround.Any suggestion?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        $(".example").click(function () {
            $.fancybox({
                href: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
                type: 'ajax',
                padding: 5,
                once: false
            });

        });
    });
</script>

<a class="example" href="javascript:;" itemprop="url">Test</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to put scripts which you are using in the head of the page

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
</head>
```

Comment: Do you reload the page somehow? Try to type $.fancybox in console (after it stops working) and tell me if the message is the same.

Comment: Sutiation goes like this: if i submit the form with ajax iframe  fancybox keeps working but if i close the screen next time i try to open it up again it throws uncaught type error fancybox is not defined.